# What languages are used in making social media sites?

Tags: web, social-media

What languages are used in making social media sites like facebook, quora, instagram and stackoverflow...etc? And why is each one of them used?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the making of such websites and web applications, the most commonly used languages are php, SQL and python(for the server side/backend) and javascript or C#(for the frontend/UI). However, most sites make use of other technologies such as SQL databases and frameworks like React, Vue.js, Angular, ASP.NET, Django, Flask etc.